# Why is app.UseAntiforgery() a compiler error in my ASP.NET Core 7 program?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, asp.net-core-7.0

I am using ASP.NET Core 7.0 and I found a code example, that shows the following:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseAntiforgery();

// Anti-forgery token validation happens for this endpoint
app.MapPost("/todo", ([FromForm] Todo todo) => Results.Ok(todo));

app.Run();
```

However, when I copy and paste the code into a project, the compiler states:

> CS1061 - 'WebApplication' does not contain a definition for 'UseAntiforgery' and no accessible extension method 'WebApplication' accepting a first argument of type 'WebApplication' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `builder.Services.AddDataProtection().SetApplicationName([Trimmed Content Root Path]);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to notice the .net version of the codes sample.

The middleware `app.UseAntiforgery()` would be avaliable in .net8,here's the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-with-minimal-apis) related,the middleware is for minimal APIs that accept form data require antiforgery token validation

For .net 7 minimal api projects we add check with the codes follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-7.0#antiforgery-with-minimal-apis-1):

```
internal static class AntiForgeryExtensions
{
    public static TBuilder ValidateAntiforgery<TBuilder>(this TBuilder builder) where TBuilder : IEndpointConventionBuilder
    {
        return builder.AddEndpointFilter(routeHandlerFilter: async (context, next) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var antiForgeryService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAntiforgery>();
                await antiForgeryService.ValidateRequestAsync(context.HttpContext);
            }
            catch (AntiforgeryValidationException)
            {
                return Results.BadRequest("Antiforgery token validation failed.");
            }

            return await next(context);

        });
    }
}

app.MapPost("api/upload", (IFormFile name) => Results.Accepted())
    .RequireAuthorization()
    .ValidateAntiforgery();
```

Comment: Your right, somehow I missed the version (8.0) in the code sample, version 7.0 does not have the UseAntiforgery() method.   Thanks!